# How to make img full height of section as showed on attached image with css?

Tags: html, css, responsive

How to make img full height of section as showed on attached image?
I'd like to do it from css level, because I'm trying to do it by going to the tablet screen from media query.
I was trying to do this with grid-template, but it wasn't working fine.
(Using scss)

[image]

```css
.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.main-content:nth-child(2n) {
  flex-direction: row;
  .main-content>*:nth-child(1) {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .main-content>*:nth-child(2) {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

.main-content>*:nth-child(1) {
  width: 60%;
}

.main-content>*:nth-child(2) {
  width: 30%;
}

.main-content>*:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .main-content {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="main-content">
  <h4>Jakie projekty można zgłaszać?</h4>
  <img class="chmurka" src="images/ilustracja_misja21-06 1.svg" alt="chmurka">


  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus dicta minima accusantium vel impedit, voluptates mollitia veniam facilis ipsum reiciendis repudiandae aperiam sequi error id. Nobis, placeat incidunt. Velit, saepe? Odio eos libero, molestias
    culpa beatae ipsam itaque, aut numquam aperiam in adipisci veniam recusandae perferendis aspernatur dolorum maxime. Eveniet magni numquam et, nulla aspernatur doloremque repudiandae aliquam nesciunt voluptate.
  </article>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is not good at all, here is an example :

```css
.main-content{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.first{
  width: 33%;
}

.second{
  width: 66%;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-content">
  <div class="first">
    <img class="chmurka" src="images/ilustracja_misja21-06 1.svg" alt="chmurka">
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <h4>Jakie projekty można zgłaszać?</h4>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus dicta minima accusantium vel impedit, voluptates mollitia veniam facilis ipsum reiciendis repudiandae aperiam sequi error id. Nobis, placeat incidunt. Velit, saepe? Odio eos libero, molestias
    culpa beatae ipsam itaque, aut numquam aperiam in adipisci veniam recusandae perferendis aspernatur dolorum maxime. Eveniet magni numquam et, nulla aspernatur doloremque repudiandae aliquam nesciunt voluptate.
  </p>
  </div>


</section>
```

Comment: **down-voted for following reason:** Answer misses a sufficient explaination of the issue. Answer misses a sufficient explaination of the solution. An answer with code only can be considered low-quality. It is hard or impossible to understand for the OP and as such also hard to reproduce.

Comment: There is no explanation given, the source code is bad

Answer (score -1):

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "i h" "i a" / min-content auto;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

img {
  grid-area: i;
}

h4 {
  grid-area: h;
  margin: 0;
}

article {
  grid-area: a;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-content">
  <h4>Jakie projekty można zgłaszać?</h4>
  <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus dicta minima accusantium vel impedit, voluptates mollitia veniam facilis ipsum reiciendis repudiandae aperiam sequi error id. Nobis, placeat incidunt. Velit, saepe? Odio eos libero, molestias
    culpa beatae ipsam itaque, aut numquam aperiam in adipisci veniam recusandae perferendis aspernatur dolorum maxime. Eveniet magni numquam et, nulla aspernatur doloremque repudiandae aliquam nesciunt voluptate.
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: @tacoshy, ok, but actually I would disagree as the answer is short enough to be clear without additional explanation.